# Comparison between string sequence and empty string

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I kind of have the answer already, but I want to understand why it works and I'm not sure yet.

I have the following variable that is filled with a matching:

```
 <xsl:variable name="invalid_characters" as="xs:string*">
   <xsl:analyze-string select="$urlToValidate" regex="{$regex}">
     <xsl:matching-substring>                
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:matching-substring>
   </xsl:analyze-string>        
 </xsl:variable>
```

Then I want the template to do something with that variable in case it isn't null or empty, so I asked like this:

```
<xsl:if test="not($invalid_characters='')">
   <error>The error</error>
</xsl:if>
```

The thing is that the if was always true... even if the variable was empty, I had to do it like this to work

```
<xsl:if test="$invalid_characters!=''">
   <error>The error</error>
</xsl:if>
```

What bothers me is that if I do something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="$invalid_characters=''">
   <error>The error</error>
</xsl:if>
```

The if statement does what it should, so, anyone knows why what I did first doesn't work as it should?

Thanks in advance :)

--- EDIT: Someone said the question is hard to understand so I'll give an example.

Here you can see a full example of the xslt with the two if statements and the input.

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//@*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@href[not(../scope) or     ../scope='local']|@conref|@conrefend">
    <xsl:variable name="urlToValidate" select="if(substring-before(.,'#')='')
                                     then .
                                     else substring-before(.,'#')"/>        
    <xsl:variable name="regex">[\$&apos;%\*\./=\\&lt;&gt;_\(\)\[\]:;,\^~\?|@!\+&amp;\}\{]</xsl:variable>        
    <xsl:variable name="invalid_characters" as="xs:string*">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$urlToValidate" regex="{$regex}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>                
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>        
    </xsl:variable>    
    <xsl:if test="not($invalid_characters='')">
        <error1>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </error1>            
    </xsl:if>               
    <xsl:if test="$invalid_characters!=''">
        <error2>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </error2>            
    </xsl:if>        
</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the input:

```
<links>
<image conrefend="GUID-6A680D85-10FA-4BCC-B57D-B5138ABE6A59" /> 
<image conrefend="GUID-1F14088D-4376-46FF-AE6F-937C2AAF5A43" /> 
<image conrefend="GUID-BB4F234D-3584-4B92-B9CB-D91FBD913B8D#GUID-BB4F234D-584-4B92-B9CB-D91FBD913B8D/MSCPDR1" />
<image conrefend="GUID-6E03D2D4-3FA9-4437-8689-06B873FB56CB" />
<image conrefend="GUID-C97E0253-73C1-4A27-B43E-7A913400BBB8" />
<image conrefend="COPY-GUI'D-86241639-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944"/>
<image conrefend="COPY-GUID-86241639-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944"/>
<image conref="COPY-GUID/*+-862416}39-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944" />
<image conrefend="COPY-GUID-8624163{9-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944"/>  
<image href="COPY-GUID-8624163&lt;9-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944" scope="local"/> 
<image href="COPY-GUID-8624163~9-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944" scope="local"/>    
</links>
```

And here is the result I get:

```
<error1>GUID-6A680D85-10FA-4BCC-B57D-B5138ABE6A59</error1>
<error1>GUID-1F14088D-4376-46FF-AE6F-937C2AAF5A43</error1>
<error1>GUID-BB4F234D-3584-4B92-B9CB-D91FBD913B8D#GUID-BB4F234D-3584-4B92-B9CB-D91FBD913B8D/MSCPDR1</error1>
<error1>GUID-6E03D2D4-3FA9-4437-8689-06B873FB56CB</error1>
<error1>GUID-C97E0253-73C1-4A27-B43E-7A913400BBB8</error1>
<error1>COPY-GUI'D-86241639-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944</error1>
<error2>COPY-GUI'D-86241639-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944</error2>
<error1>COPY-GUID-86241639-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944</error1>
<error1>COPY-GUID/*+-862416}39-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944</error1>
<error2>COPY-GUID/*+-862416}39-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944</error2>
<error1>COPY-GUID-8624163{9-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944</error1>
<error2>COPY-GUID-8624163{9-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944</error2>
<error1>COPY-GUID-8624163&lt;9-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944</error1>
<error2>COPY-GUID-8624163&lt;9-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944</error2>
<error1>COPY-GUID-8624163~9-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944</error1>
<error2>COPY-GUID-8624163~9-37CD-4CF7-A7AA-F09F4A763944</error2>
```

As you can see, there is an error1 tag for every entry, and an error2 tag only for those cases where it should be.

Any ideas of why the first comparison doesn't work as I think it should?

Comment: So you use `analyze-string` to extract a sequence of substrings from your attribute values. When do you consider a sequence of strings to be "null", when it is an empty sequence? What do you want to check with your `=''` comparison, that there is at least one item in the sequence that is the empty string?

Comment: The `=''` should evaluate that the sequence is empty, or I'm not thinking of it correctly?

Comment: As sequence is empty with the check `count($seq) eq 0` or `not(exists($seq))` or `not($seq)`. A comparison `$seq = ''` checks that at least one item in the sequence is equal to the empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable is a **sequence**, either containing zero, one or several strings (whether each string could be empty or not depends on the specific regex).

### Comparisons between the empty sequence and the empty string:

The empty sequence is not the same thing as the empty string; comparisons between the empty sequence and the empty string always return false:

```
() = ''    false
() != ''   false
```

### Comparisons between a single-item sequence and the empty string:

A sequence containing a single string is equivalent to that string (see the [XPath Data Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#sequences)), so it can *either* be the empty string *or (exclusive or)* be different from the empty string:

```
('') = ''      true
('') != ''     false

('foo') = ''   false
('foo') != ''  true
```

### Comparisons between a multi-item sequence and the empty string:

Two sequences are "equal" if they have at least a common item, and "different" if they have at least a different item. So, two sequences could be *both* equal *and* different.

This also applies when comparing a multi-item sequence and a string, as we already have seen that a string is equivalent to a sequence containing just that string:

```
('', '') = ''           true
('', '') != ''          false

('foo', 'bar') = ''     false
('foo', 'bar') != ''    true

('foo', '') = ''        true
('foo', '') != ''       true
```

### Conclusion:

While working with sequences, checking `$a != $b` **is not equivalent to** checking `not($a = $b)`

Answer (score 3):

The following **didn't work** for you:

```
<xsl:if test="not($invalid_characters='')">
    <error>The error</error>
</xsl:if>
```

because, an empty sequence is not equal to anything(it isn't equal to another empty sequence either). Try, `<xsl:value-of select="() = ()"/>` and you'll get `false`.
Hence, for an empty sequence the condition was always `true`.

**Why this worked**:

```
<xsl:if test="$invalid_characters!=''">
    <error>The error</error>
</xsl:if>
```

is because, for an empty sequence, this always gets evaluated to `false`. Try: `<xsl:value-of select="() != ()"/>` and you would get `false`(empty sequence is neither equal nor not-equal to anything).
Here the sequence, if contains at least one item, which isn't a null string would return `true`. Hence, would fail to do the job for empty or null string.